# Check if type is assignable not working with primitive types

Tags: java

Is it normal that `boolean.class.isAssignableFrom(Boolean.class)` and `Boolean.class.isAssignableFrom(boolean.class)` return `false`?

The same thing for `Integer` and `int`.

So how to really check if type is assignable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is normal, and there is nothing in the standard library to help. You probably want something like Guava's [Primitives](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/primitives/Primitives.html).unwrap and wrap methods.

Answer (score 0):

This worked: 
if (field.getType().toString().equals("boolean"))...